How to recompile a project developed with an old version of Expo sdk today (2024)?
I got a copy of the original code developed using react native and the "suspected" expo SDK 37.0.7. I want to recompile and enable this code. Is this possible? I am new to RN, can anyone tell me how to get started? Thank you very much! !
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "expo": "~37.0.7",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "~16.12.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-dom": "~16.12.0",
    "react-intl": "^5.13.2",
    "react-native": "~0.63.5",
    "react-native-animated-splash-screen": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.43.6",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^7.2.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.6.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-accessory": "^0.1.16",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.30.2",
    "react-native-markdown-display": "^6.1.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-paper": "4.1.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "~6.3.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.3",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.17",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-select-input-ios": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-snackbar-reddit": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.0.6",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-text-ticker": "^1.14.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.13",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-maps-polyline": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "with-immutable-props-to-js": "^1.0.2"

I have tried to install the expo module, but the installation is the new version 51.0.32, and there are many errors in the process, so I am thinking whether I should first use expo 37.0.7 (specified in the project app.json file) After the original code can run normally, continue to update to the latest version of the sdk.
I also tested according to the following discussion thread, but the discussion explained how to recommend an empty old version of the development environment, but what I got was an existing project
Create an expo project with a specific version
